# Ring buffer mode for GPIO

Tags: beagleboneblack

Beaglebone Black libpruio allows using the ring buffer mode to sample the analog inputs with a constant time interval. Is it possible to use the ring buffer mode to sample and store the values of selected analog inputs AND a the states of a few selected GPIO pins?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible. At least with the current version 0.4 compiled from source:

[github.com/dtjf/libpruio](http://github.com/dtjf/libpruio)

The GPIO sampling may be a little slower than in IO mode, depending on the ADC sampling rate.

Other actions like PWM, CAP, QEP and GPIO.output are also possible, in RB as well as MM mode. (In MM you'll need a second thread to handle that.)